# used wrong ubuntu mirror to install packages

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get

I work with a computer system that has a ubuntu mirror locally installed. The OS is ubuntu 9.10 (karmic) Server. I see that a colleague changed the regular /etc/apt/sources.list file to access the local mirror, but it points to only the 10.0.4 (lucid) packages.

Now, a number of packages have been installed and do not work properly. I'm not certain which ones they are. I've thought that it may be easiest to write a script to uninstall every installed package and then reinstall each from the correct distro to repair the system. Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: With this limited amount of information, and your apparent unfamiliarity with the system, I don't think yours is a feasible approach. Back up user data and perhaps your debconf settings and reinstall.